# How much protein from the stock of one large chicken (2kg) carcass once legs, breasts and wings removed?

Tags: chicken, stock

I can find details of how much protein per body of fluid (e.g. 1 US cup) but to be honest we probably all make stock to a different concentration, so that makes that metric useless.

When I prepare a large chicken (2kg), I remove the breasts , wings and legs (and the oysters on the back) so I'm left with just the main carcass which I then simmer for ages.  How much protein is extracted please?

Answer (score 1):

Search on chicken back bone nutrition. Many hits.

From this [link](https://www.eatthismuch.com/food/view/chicken-back,442/) about 20 grams per 102g of total mass.

Comment: Ok, this is useful, thanks.  But I did ask about stock.